# Is there something wrong with the hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash, hats

I have earned the `Fascinating` hat on Stack Overflow a few hours ago. Then I choose to wear the hat. Now I went to Ask Ubuntu and noticed I have the had here too - and on many other sites I got it after clicking on it too. The funny thing is that Winter Bash tells me I only have the had on Stack Overflow and nowhere else:

[image]

Is it normal that I can wear hats that I only have on one site on all other sites too or is this a bug in Winter Bash?

Comment: Notice the "only on this site" checkbox above "Wear hat" button. If it's not checked then it will be applied globally to all accounts just as Seth answered :)

Comment: @AndrewT. I was just wondering why I can wear a hat on a site where I didn't get that hat - I thought that option will only wear that hat on all sites I have earned it before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wear hats globally, they just don't count towards the site specific leaderboards unless you earn them on that specific site.